# Retrieve only one value(forKey: ) from Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Right now I have used a breakpoint to check the value at each step of the method. The print statement works so I know it is going through. The value of newAnnotationSubtitle is  "1 Cupertino CA, US" and I want to check if the `annotationSubtitle` in my Database is the same. `let existingAnnotationSubtitle` returns nil but I know there is a value. I can't seem to access the `key: value`. What can I change?

For reference, `placemarkName = "Apple Infinite Loop"`

```
let annotationRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "annotationItems")

annotationRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

   print("IT WORKS")

   if snapshot.hasChild(placemarkName!) {
       let newAnnotationSubtitle: String = preAnnotationListItem.preAnnotationSubtitle
       let existingAnnotationSubtitle = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: placemarkName!).value(forKey: "annotationSubtitle")! as? String

   }
```

My JSON looks like this

```
"annotationItems" : {
   "Apple Infinite Loop" : {
     "annotationSubtitle" : "1 Cupertino CA, US",
   }
}
```